# How to test function in AngularJS service with mock data

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-service

How to create Jasmine unit test for one function in AngularJS service provider. I want to create mock data for myObject and test function getObjectShape() with that mock data as parameter. How to achieve that?

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('objectShapes')
            .provider('shapesResolver', shapesResolver);

        function shapesResolver() {

            this.$get = function () {
                return resolver;
            };

            function resolver(myObject) {

                var service = {
                    getObjectShape: getObjectShape
                };

                function getObjectShape() {
                    return myObject.Shape;
                }
            }
        }
})();
```

Comment: I don't see any dependency here, I don't understand which mock data you're talking about, and your resolver() function does nothing other than declaring a variable and doing nothing with it. So I'm a bit confused. Also, you forgot to post what you tried.

Comment: I said that I need to create mock data for myObject which is parameter of function resolver. Ok, it was my mistake, it has no dependencies. I need simple structure of unit test for function resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a skeleton of a test for your service.

```
describe('shapesResolver service', function() {
    var shapesResolver;

    beforeEach(module('objectShapes'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_shapesResolver_) {
        shapesResolver = _shapesResolver_;
    }));

    it('should do something, but what?', function() {
        var mockMyObject = {};

        shapesResolver(mockMyObject);

        // shapesResolver doesn't return anything, and doesn't 
        // have any side effect, so there's nothing to test.

        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    }); 
});
```